# Share model classes between two WPF apps?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model

I have a solution hierarchy as follows:

Solution
--Main Application (WPF)
-----UI (Views and ViewModels)
-----BLL
-----DAL
-----MODEL (entity classes)
--Sub Application (version1. Separate sub app for new versions in future)
-----UI (Views and ViewModels)
-----BLL
-----DAL
-----MODEL (entity classes)

Some of the entity class definitions from main application project will be required in Sub application layers. Is there a better approach apart from 'adding reference of MainApplication.Model class library into sub application'?

Comment: Why isn't `adding reference of MainApplication.Model class library into sub application` a good enough approch?

Comment: You could make the Model classes their own project and reference in both Main and Sub applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest sa_ddam213 the cleanest way for me is to create a whole project for the model part.
Then you could reference it from any project needing it.

Also you could keep the model layer in the other project to adapt the external model to your project.